# How can I protect my app from Google itself?

Tags: android

I made a simple app that stores bank account, money transactions and other sensible data. Stored data is already encrypted, with no network access at all and closed to itself. But how can I make sure that other apps or the OS itself is not trying to read data the app generates? Are there trustable methods to see when and/or how my app is being tracked or read, even by the OS and log that "suspicious" activity?

I Tried to google that and read Developers manuals, but found nothing.

Comment: You just have to make sure to hide your data as best as possible, asymmetric encryption [...] aslo you have to know that the vast majority of android is open source and the different google services (which is not open source) works like standard applications that means that he got the same sandbox environement than any apps (expected some privileges) and in theory it will never be able to read other applications data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are saying that your data is

> already encrypted

And not looking for a better encryption methods. Then you are basically asking a question not much different from: "Can I forbid for an OS an access to the screen buffer, and render my decrypted data directly on a hardware?"

The only totally safe solution to this problem is to create your own OS.

But then again... you must ask yourself: do you trust hardware manufacturers? Or that you hardware won't be somehow infected. https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/bios-level-malware

Other options are:

1. Trust in open source.
2. Participate in open source and audit software you are using.
3. And there is always a security through obscurity: if you are not a millionaire bad guys won't bother wasting their time to break even a simplest protection.

Comment: Simple, but this is the answer for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the **SHA256** algorithm method in your app logic.

This  algorithm requires a **salt** to be required in order to encrypt and decrypt the text.

Without this salt, ***no one*** not even Google or OS in your case can access your sensitive data.

If you have your project on Github then put this salt inside a **file_name.env** (extension for the environment file) and add this file in **.gitignore** so that this secret salt key is not stored on the server and is with you itself!

Hence, no one can access your encrypted sensitive data!

Follow the Official android doc:
[Android Developer doc for SHA256 Message Digest](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest)

Comment: and how can the app use that salt? should the user enter it while opening the app?

Comment: You can generate a Random salt for more security everytime or else create a global salt string and use it commonly throughout.
your question: "Should the user enter it while opening the app" - If you want to allow the user to enter a password while opening the data, you can let the user create a salt_string -> store it -> fetch it -> decrypt using that salt and read th data

Comment: This means the .env file is not read by the OS at all while  executing (or compiling)? I mean, the salt will be in the app nonetheless.

Comment: yup, that salt you're using to encrypt/decrypt the data will be stored inside the app anyways and will be accessible for the intruder as well

Comment: If you don't trust OS, nothing can be done to secure in "that" way. But the best option would be to maybe store salt outside of app, for example download it from backend each time when app starts. You can google how to safely store api key, it should be useful for salt too

Comment: U can use a very large random string as the key for the algorithm. This way it will be really very difficult for anyone to crack the data! What else u want than this for a better solution.

Comment: Your question that u want the salt to be kept only to yourself....then store the salt on your server nd access it in the app from there itself....or else....use fileinputstream methods to store nd access that salt from your phone storage

Comment: Nd even if your OS reads the salt by any chance how can anyone decrypt such a long key password nd sensible data.

Comment: @PrajwalW the problem resides not in app level, but OS/kernel level.

Comment: Google isnt an OS/kernel.

Comment: What I mean is if Google has total control of the OS, implementing an app level solution still can expose data to Google (or anything that controls the OS/kernel). That was exactly my question, how can somebody make a really secure app?

Answer (score 3):

Protecting your app's data from other apps is the operating system's job. There are a few things you have to get right to ensure this, such as protecting the key you use to sign your apk. There are also a few things your users have to do (which are out of your control), such as not root their phone and then grant root access to other apps. Programming-wise, there's nothing too specific. Most inter-app data sharing is opt-in.

Protecting your app's data from the operating system is a high bar--especially as you describe: if the operating system were to *try* to see your app's data. It's common to assume, for analysis, that it knows everything about your app's design and can be arbitrarily dishonest. We'd assume advisory measures, such as opting out of app data backup and setting "private" mode on the on-screen keyboard don't do what they claim.

Unfortunately, protecting your app from the operating system/vendor is not something well supported in Android. And depending on your personal views, you might consider that the operating system having access to your app's data equivalent to the operating system vendor (indeed, Google in the case of Pixel phones) having access to your app's data--especially if they can deliver operating system upgrades automatically.

A key problem is that input and output go through the operating system. A user's taps on the screen go through the operating system first before the operating system conveys them to your app. You might then encrypt it, but it's already too late. Later you would decrypt something to show it to the user. But descriptions of what to show on screen go through the operating system before the operating system conveys them to the screen.

As the question asks about the current state of Android, the answer is that there's no (general) way to isolate your app's data from the operating system.

But there are two positive things I want to point out in this answer:

1. There's hope for certain specific kinds of data.

   - You can isolate cryptographic keys. Android comes with a keystore system that's well separated from the operating system. With this, you can, for example, create digital signatures without exposing the key to the operating system.
   - You might be able to display some content, if only it were generated and encrypted off of the device. Digital rights management (DRM), referring to the technology that tries to keep people from bootlegging movies, is supposed to make a safe path from a content owner to the screen without much other stuff being able to 'see' it. I don't have much details on this though, and I don't know if any of it really keeps the operating system out as practically implemented
2. You can also do some good if you're willing to consider a weaker threat model, where you say the operating system starts out 'good' and then turns evil at a later date (e.g., it gets compromised by an attacker). In this situation, the encryption you mention starts to be useful. You can make it so that the attacker can't *immediately* access the app's data. They'd have to wait for the user to put in the encryption password or something like that. But you'd have to figure out how much that's worth.

Comment: I wasn't really expecting someone to provide such details for this complex question. Kudos for providing alternatives, even when there's really no easy solution. About DRM, "newer" Linux kernels already have it and I think that's the path we could go for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use some encryption which relies on a custom secrete key and part of that secret key has been provided by the user himself. Also, be careful about the apps which have screen record permission they might run a foreground service, pretend doing something else (screenshot) while trying capture your app on display info. It's a rare case, I think I am just trying to be super protective here

Answer (score 0):

If your app is persisting data, use [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences).

If your app is sending data to the cloud, it is encrypted with SSL/HTTPS. You can further write [encrypt / decrypt](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography) logic in your API calls for adding another level of indirection.